# Random number as file name

Tags: python, random, filenames, fopen

So, I want to put a random number as my filename in `f=open`
I generated the number with `d=random.randint(1,10)`
and I want to put that as my filename in `f=open`.

`f=open("test.txt", "x")`

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not hard.  What have you tried?  Formatting strings like this is exactly like formatting strings for printing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you tried very hard to solve this yourself.

```
d = random.randint(1,10)
f = open(f"test{d}.txt",'w')
```